# HTML document - can't prevent object dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a web app that's available for testing on:

> "http://83.150.87.220/dropbox/HelsinkiViSeZip/Jatkasaari"

It is used (mainly) to zoom in on an image and pan that same image.

Once the document loads and the central image becomes visible, you can `mousedown + drag` to either `zoom in/out` on that image or pan it.

When pressing the mouse button down, you'll notice that the image turns blurry and that an indicator (png image) appears just under the cursor. That indicator shows you how to move the cursor in order to select an action (zoom/pan).

Everything works just fine in Chrome, but in FF, once you `mousedown` for the second time on the image and start dragging the cursor, it seems that the indicator (the `png` image I mentioned earlier) drags along and messes everything up. This seems to be pretty much the default behavior for clicking-dragging images in any browser. But it's very weird, since on the first `mousedown+cursor drag` combination, everything works just fine. And not to mention that I made sure to prevent the default action for images:

```
$(document).on('mousedown dragstart', 'img, a.icon', function(event) {  
    event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

I'm all dried up in terms of ideas on how to find the problem, so I'm going out of my mind...Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting it as a background image inside of a div container or something similar and just show/hide that instead of using an img element. That way you won't be able to actually "select" the image with the cursor but everything should still work if it's driven by javascript.

Comment: That would be preferred, yes. Unfortunately, the size of that PNG is dependent on window size. Which means I need to use an <img> tag for it, otherwise I can't control the height and width.

Comment: Ah, I see :( Well, if you are planning to target newer browsers you could use CSS3 http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem and it seems that it need to also `return false;` to prevent the browser default behavior.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eloyesp/RS9vR/3/)